# how to store value of ansible fact variable in another variable

Tags: linux, ansible, ansible-playbook

I wanted to store value of ansible fact variable in some other variable, and also wanted to check is that fact variable is empty or not

Below is my code where i can print the value of ansible_local fact variable but i wanted that value to store in another variable say xyz. And also wanted to check that ansible_local.sj.inventory.as_tag variable value is empty or not

```
- name: -> Apply common configuration to {{ target }} nodes
  hosts: "{{ target }}"
  gather_facts: True

  user: root

  pre_tasks:
   - setup:
      filter: ansible_local

 tasks:
   - action: debug msg="{{ ansible_local.sj.inventory.as_tag }}"
```

Sample O/P:

```
TASK: [debug msg="{{ansible_local.sj.inventory.as_tag}}"]   
    ***********
Monday 09 May 2016  09:48:49 -0700 (0:00:01.375)       0:00:02.785  
  ************
ok: [abcserver] => {
  "msg": "abcd-123"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [set_fact module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/set_fact_module.html).

Here is an example....

```
- name: -> Apply common configuration to {{ target }} nodes
  hosts: "{{ target }}"
  gather_facts: True
  user: root

  pre_tasks:
   - setup:
      filter: ansible_local
   - set_fact:
       tag: "{{ ansible_local.sj.inventory.as_tag }}"
   - debug:
       var: tag
```